# instagram api - retrieve user id / username from client side authorization only?

Tags: javascript, instagram

Reading up on Instagram's api.  Anyone know of a way to retrieve the user's id via client side auth (javascript)? Possibly with the client id or acces token that is returned from:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token
```

I see a solution for server side, but working  with some limitations. Thanks.

https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: If you've found an answer to your own question, post it as an answer! No shame in figuring it out on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some tinkering around, it's not the cleanest solution, but...it works.

you can use this endpoint:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

and can retrieve the username from any of the objects